# VBA to insert new line in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the below code to insert lines in a word document. I want to enter 3 blank lines to print Line2. How to code VBA to insert 3 blank lines in a word document so that I can print Line2 after that.

```
   Line1 = "Line1 hello"
   Line2 = "Line2 hello"
   
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
   objWord.Visible = True
   
   ' objWord.ActiveDocument.Styles ("Heading 2")
   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
   objSelection.Font.Bold = True
   objSelection.Font.Name = "Arial"
   objSelection.TypeText (Line1)
```

Comment: Is this code running from Excel? Why don’t you use IntelliSense, the Object Browser, or online help to look up what options you have? For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertparagraphafter

Comment: Have you tried appending 3 `vbCrLf` constants after Line 1?

Comment: As in `Line1 = "Line1 hello" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & vbcrlf`

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It worked after using vbCrLf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

```
Public Sub MakeWordDoc()
    
    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set wd = New Word.Application
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Add
    wd.Visible = True
    
    doc.Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = "Line 1 hello"
    
    For i = 1 To 4
        doc.Paragraphs.Add
    Next i
    
    doc.Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = "Line 2 hello"
    
End Sub
```

I don't know why I have to add four paragraphs to get three blank lines, but when I add text to the last paragraph, it deletes the blank before it.

Here's another way
Public Sub MakeWordDoc()

```
    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set wd = New Word.Application
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Add
    wd.Visible = True
    
    Set para = doc.Paragraphs.Add
    para.Range.Text = "Line 1 hello"
    para.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 18
    
    doc.Paragraphs.Add
    doc.Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = "Line 2 hello"
    
End Sub
```

You can make the 18 whatever you want - it's in points. Again, I had to add a blank paragraph for line 2 to eat up, which I don't understand. Hopefully this gives you enough to work out the details on your own.

Comment: `para.Range.Text` includes the end of paragraph mark. By replacing the text with a string that does not include `vbCr` you combine that paragraph with the following one.

Comment: Thanks @TimothyRylatt That was bugging me.